# How to download streamlit output as html file

Tags: python, html, visual-studio-code, report, streamlit

I generated an interactive output in Streamlit; I need to download the output as an HTML file in local.
By clicking the button, the download has to be initiated.
Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: Have you checked the download_button documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read [document](https://streamlit-release-demos-0-88streamlit-app-0-88-v8ram3.streamlit.app/#download-a-dataframe-converted-to-a-csv), there exists an example about **.csv** file.

Here I can give an example about html:

```
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st


df=pd.read_csv("test.csv")

@st.cache
def convert_df(df):
    return df.to_html().encode('utf-8')

html = convert_df(df)

st.download_button(
    "Press to Download",
    html,
    "test.html"
)
```

[image]

[image]